# Saving an array to get_options

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, functions, options

1. I'm trying to save an array to get_options in wordpress, I'm aware that I don't have to serialize the array due to get_options doing that.
2. At the moment I don't get any success of failed message upon hitting the submit button.
3. Am I adding the input data correctly to the database using get_options and update_options. If not how can my code be tweaked to accomplish this.

   add_action('admin_menu', 'dw_quotes_create_menu');

   ```
   function dw_quotes_create_menu() {
       //create custom top-level menu
       add_menu_page('Quotes Settings', 'Quotes Styling', 'manage_options', 'dw_quotes', 'dw_styling_quotes_settings');
   }

       //generating the random quote
   function dw_get_random_quote() {


   }

   function validate_dw_quote() {
       //validation here
       if (isset($_POST['submit'] ) ) {

           //checking that $_POST['adding_quote'] is set
           if( isset( $_POST['adding_quote'] ) ) {

               //retrieve the stored values
               if( get_option( 'list_of_quotes' ) )
                   $list_of_quotes = get_option('list_of_quotes');
               else 
                   $list_of_quotes = array();

               //add the new quote to the end of the array 
               $list_of_quotes[] = $_POST['adding_quote'];

               //store the updated quote
               if ( update_option( 'list_of_quotes', $list_of_quotes ) ) {
                   echo "Success your quote was added!";
               } else {
                   echo "Failed to add quote!";
               }
           }
       }
   }

       //styling the admin menu
   function dw_styling_quotes_settings() { ?>
       <h2>Quote Setting</h2>

       <form action="admin.php?page=dw_quotes" method="post">
       <label for="add">Enter your quote</label>
       <input type="textarea"  name="adding_quote" />
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add the new quote" />

       <?php //test the output 
       var_dump($list_of_quotes);
       ?>
   ```

Comment: where do you call `validate_dw_quote`?

Comment: Put `die;` after your `//store the updated quote` `if/else` block. Do you see the message now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for it to save the data you need to hook your `validate_dw_quote()` onto to an action, such as admin_init or init.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'validate_dw_quote');
```

Comment: Hi Eric, could you tell me if the options are shared between users or user specific? I was thinking about using them on snippets. Thanks